# checkbox label doesn't work on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

I want to use a pure css cookie bar plugin, but when I want to close the cookie bar, it doesn't work in IE9 and I don't really know why I'm in front of this problem ?

Here are the original [CODEPEN][1] and my [JSFIDDLE][2] that I want to use.

```
[1]: http://codepen.io/natewiley/pen/uGtcD<br>
[2]: https://jsfiddle.net/kodjoe/L2pw9752/3/
```

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle to reproduce this?

Comment: Sorry i forget the link, I just updated my question

Comment: I added it to my question @mwilson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added my own function via js, my goal is to slide up when i click on X, thank you for all your help ;D

```
$(function(){
$('.close-cb').click(function(){
$('.cookie-bar').slideUp();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Codepen does not support IE9](http://codepen.io/unsupported/):

```
Our desktop browser support is:
•Chrome 1+
•Firefox 4+
•Safari 4+
•Opera 11+
•IE 10+
```

Your jsfiddle doesn't seem to work at all, regardless of browser, but that is because its CSS preprocessor is not set to "SCSS" (as it is set in your codepen).

I'm not running IE9, but if I visit your jsfiddle link in IE11, change IE's "Document mode emulated" setting to "9" (in Dev Tools), change the fiddle's CSS preprocessor to "SCSS", then click "Run", your cookie bar does close as expected when I click the "X".

For your actual page, you can use an online converter such as [this one](http://sass.js.org/) to convert your SASS to CSS. Then, include the resulting CSS in your HTML instead of the SCSS.

Comment: You are right @MJR  why it doesn't work only on IE ? and How can I transform my SCSS code to simple CSS rules to see it working with IE ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "why it doesn't work only on IE". As I mentioned, my fiddle does work in IE11 using IE9 Document Mode.  Regarding transformation, see the last paragraph in my modified answer.

Comment: in my IE9 it doesn't work when i put scss instead of css, but i have to convert my scss in css !!! i try to and come back ;D